# FreeTDS: Do I need to restart anything after changing the freetds.conf file?

Tags: freetds

The freetds.log file was overloading the system, so I changed the debug flags in /etc/freetds.conf :

```
    ;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
    #;      debug flags = 0xffff
    ;       debug flags = 0x80
```

How do I restart freetds or unixodbc? Nothing is taking effect, even when I comment out the `dump file = /tmp/freetds.log` line.

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be anyone who knows, but I figured it out.

So it is automatic. If it doesn't look like your changes have taken effect, it is because you are editing the wrong file. I had 2 freetds.conf files in different locations. Do a `locate freetds.conf` and you'll see that you have multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience I found that changes to the freetds.conf file were not applied until I actually rebooted the machine itself.

I had simply changed the log file location and the debug level, but only once the server was rebooted did I see these changes being taken into account.

Prior to rebooting the server (which was done because nothing else I tried seemed to work) I tried to restart the various services which I though would impact, namely nginx, but this did not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, i know. But it has no accepted answer yet and hopefully this could add some value. :)

Using Freetds as part of PHP development (with nginx etc) we need to restart PHP FPM for the changes to come into effect.